# WIFI not working on Macbook pro 19.04

Tags: wireless, mac, 19.04

After installing the new release 19.04 I haven't been able to get the wifi to work. I had 18.04 and I had a little trouble getting the wifi to work, but I was able to get it after a while reading different forums. This time the drivers shows up on the update app and it appears to be activated, but when I search for the wifi on the settings it says "wifi adapter not found." I've tried pretty much everything I tried when I installed 18.04LTS and it has not work, so I'm pretty frustrated at this point...

Comment: on any driver question especially wifi always show your hardware ... update your question with output of running ...  lspci | grep -i network ... also show ... sudo lshw -C network ... to get good formatting highlight output from terminal then to copy  hit control-shift-c   (on mac I believe it would be apple-shift-c ) then paste output from your terminal  into an editor then highlight all and hit tab to shift everything over then copy all and paste into this question

Comment: it sounds like you didn't manage to find exaclty the thing you did with 18.04? is that true? what is the exact type and make of your wifi card?

Comment: :~$ lspci | grep -i network
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)

Comment: :~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for macpro-linux: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0600000-b0607fff memory:b0400000-b05fffff

Comment: @ScottStensland those were the results I got from the commands you asked to plug in

Comment: detailed solution at https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: @Henry Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.